# CRM 2011 How to update an account form (address1_city field) with info of specific Contact?

Tags: javascript, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I want to write JavaScript code that updates an account form (address1_city field) 
according to "Primary Contact" field, i need to retrieve the right contact city and update
the account city with this value.

How can i do that?

I have a function that returns the first contact:

```
function getFirstContactToBePrimaryContact(contactName) 
{ 
    SDK.REST.retrieveMultipleRecords("Contact", "$select=FullName", 
        function (results) 
        { 
            var firstResult = results[0]; 

            if (firstResult != null) 
            { 
                if(contactName == firstResult) 
                { 
                    returnValue = getcity(firstResult);
                    return; 
                }
            } 
            else 
            { 
                //document.write("No Contact records are available to set as the primary contact for the account.");
            } 
        }, errorHandler, function () { /*OnComplete handler*/ } 
    ); 
}
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the MSDN or SDK yet?

Comment: yes, and i didn't find the right syntax, it's a complicated one..

Comment: Post what you have so far then.

Comment: i have a function that returns the first contact:

Comment: Instead or retreiving multiple records, you can pull single contact based on contact id `contact c = (contact) service.Retrieve(EntityName.contact.ToString(), ContactId, new AllColumns());`